# Cookies conversion in Node.js

Tags: node.js, cookies, setcookie

HI Guys Need a help in cookies

In one Login call i am getting this Cookie as response header but i need the format which is below for next requests:

**Response header which i am getting** [ 'ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS=c26d807e1aaeccd5aadfffc649b97688; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure',
  'ApplicationGatewayAffinity=c26d807e1aaeccd5aadfffc649b97688; Path=/',
  '.DWPLATFORMAUTH=; expires=Wed, 29-Apr-2020 13:39:20 GMT; path=/DocuWare/Platform; HttpOnly',
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path=/; HttpOnly',
  'DWPLATFORMBROWSERID=; expires=Wed, 29-Apr-2020 13:39:20 GMT; path=/DocuWare/Platform; HttpOnly',
  'DWPLATFORMBROWSERID=FF3A3868BB062A8E1C06EA73E419443B8DC6F073D8C3A8A3988AA9CC808C8FF369099345538486B3FA99DFEC097533BBBD621A12C12E0522521846D2D953F6D2C41DC91EAFFE3A442BC3DA738324F9A063DB88695243E19934325806DBF12D7579CA3BCCFF252A276F68334BD000358948860B23976C81326D8E571B0862045760C5B6FB9115C4F7715E951EC6AE0B779E017433676EAE7D7D202E9EE2ED83C1614317CE122828FF5D980BED4D57524F3BABF60AFFC70EA09D02E0001DD1603B952B03FE3436831E7E148EF1C76BB9A3B6F14940CFAA918A183664A586D049ED; expires=Fri, 30-Apr-2021 13:39:20 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly' ]

**but other request are accepting cookies in this format Which i need **:
'ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS=71020739a3120956b31575e6a26cf347; ApplicationGatewayAffinity=71020739a3120956b31575e6a26cf347; .DWPLATFORMAUTH=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; DWPLATFORMBROWSERID=D95CC701A52B6A15866C5A3966734BD6CF400DB18961F0E8FDA9B7D0F221544DC1D48799617FADC4CDA8F52CC5EBED9F1F8ECAB3969BA913E9DD3B2C346AB09E4083BABC307A4D41B0F3C436BCC5CBD2AC159480E5A48E7101B6BA0442F192B3AF38C00ECF9F3262FCFA911CF1EAF42BACAE869CCB176E49978860225D0FD614D4C2AA9B2BDE9CD376FBFFC16462622CB5235FF9D1F6DE2DDB2F4DADD2CA4497AE388C1745B12D7133FCCE0CF7A11292F49C33DDB25268C44C75C94BB381F2530D820A2FD886F5D36C1A853ECD84136B2541605C85C79C40DB73AF85DDA7701C'

Comment: This is a little difficult to diagnose as it is; could you tell us about the tools you are using? My first thought is, given that the information you need is actually present in both cookie formats, you could use a regular expression to convert one format into the other.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelEricOberlin yes both cookies has the same info but 1st one is array , So need to iterate over array and make one string of whole array

Comment: I think you've got your answer there. I strongly suggest looking into regular expressions ("regex") because most languages support them, and this is fundamentally what they exist to do. Good luck.